# Postgres function with jsonb parameters

Tags: database, postgresql, function, stored-procedures, pgadmin

I have seen a similar post here but my situation is slightly different from anything I've found so far.  I am trying to call a postgres function with parameters that I can leverage in the function logic as they pertain to the jsonb query.  Here is an example of the query I'm trying to recreate with parameters.

```
SELECT * 
  from edit_data 
  where ( "json_field"#>'{Attributes}' )::jsonb @> 
                    '{"issue_description":"**my description**",  
                      "reporter_email":"**user@generic.com**"}'::jsonb
```

I can run this query just fine in PGAdmin but all my attempts thus far to run this inside a function with parameters for "my description" and "user@generic.com" values have failed.  Here is a simple example of the function I'm trying to create:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_Features(
    p1 character varying,
    p2 character varying)
  RETURNS SETOF edit_metadata AS
$BODY$ 
SELECT * from edit_metadata where ("geo_json"#>'{Attributes}' )::jsonb @> '{"issue_description":**$p1**, "reporter_email":**$p2**}'::jsonb;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

I know that the syntax is incorrect and I've been struggling with this for a day or two.  Can anyone help me understand how to best deal with these double quotes around the value and leverage a parameter here?

TIA

Comment: It is a String, just concatenate it like `'{"issue_description":"'||yourParam||'"` and so on.

Comment: I have also tried something along these lines:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customentitywithserializeddatatest7(
    p1 character varying,
    p2 character varying)
  RETURNS SETOF edit_metadata AS
$BODY$ 
SELECT * from edit_metadata where ( "geo_json"#>'{Attributes}' )::jsonb @> '{"issue_description":COALESCE($1, issue_description), "reporter_email":COALESCE($2, reporter_email)}'::jsonb;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;

Comment: You still don't get it, this `'{"issue_description":"**my description**", "reporter_email":"**user@generic.com**"}'` is a String and as so you cant use funcion, command or variables inside it and hope postgresql will understand, it is not PHP, you have to say to it that you are forming a NEW string. It should be like (for your case): `'{"issue_description":"'||p1||'",  "reporter_email":"'||p2||'"}'` That way you are telling to postgresql that you want to "inject" your parameter inside your String

Comment: Hey Jorge, please see the next post.

Comment: What post are you talking about? Another question or another comment?

Comment: sry, first post here, couldn't fit what I needed to in the comment.

Comment: If I understand my function should look like this.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_customentitywithserializeddatatest7(p1 character varying,  p2 character varying)
RETURNS SETOF edit_metadata AS
$BODY$ 
SELECT * from edit_metadata where ( "geo_json"#>'{Attributes}' )::jsonb @> '{"issue_description":"'||p1||'", "reporter_email":"'||p2||'"}'::jsonb;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;

Comment: When I try to build that I receive this error:
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
            LINE 6: ...ta where ( "geo_json"#>'{Attributes}' )::jsonb @> '{"issue_d...
                                                                         ^
            DETAIL:  Token """ is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use function [json_build_object](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE):

```
select json_build_object(
    'issue_description', '**my description**',
    'reporter_email', '**user@generic.com**');
```

And you get:

```
                                    json_build_object                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"issue_description" : "**my description**", "reporter_email" : "**user@generic.com**"}
(1 row)
```

That way there's no way you will input invalid syntax (no hassle with quoting strings) and you can swap the values with parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your response hruske, I'm looking into this but still unclear how to implement it with my current scenario as I'm very new to Postgres and jsonb in particular.

Comment: json_build_object turned the key, thank you very much!